# Changing unit less CSS values with JS functions

Tags: javascript, css

I want to modify the unitless zoom value of a div with a function. I know I could do this with a bunch of else if statements but I want many zoom levels, so I would prefer to have the function look if the div is at full zoom and if not then double the zoom value.
With the function below I am trying to set a variable from the current zoom value, change that to an integer, if the integer is 8 then keep zoom at 8, if the integer is anything else then double that number, then convert back to a string and set as the zoom value.

```
<script>
    function zoomIn() {
      var zoomNow = (document.getElementById('mainVP').style.zoom);
      zoomNow = Number(zoomNow);
      if (zoomNow == 8) {
        document.getElementById('mainVP').style.zoom = 8;
      } else {
        zoomNow = zoomNow*2;
        toString(zoomNow);
        document.getElementById('mainVP').style.zoom = zoomNow;
      }
}</script>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with "many zoom levels"?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you're showing?

Comment: Zoom levels will be 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8. The 'zoom levels' being the style.zoom value. If else statements wouldn't be a problem to create but I feel understanding how to write the code above will be more beneficial to my knowledge. The code doesn't seem to do anything at all so I don't know whats wrong with it at the moment.

Comment: Please do share a [minimal, concrete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The way you're setting the `zoom` property actually works.

Comment: Good to know I'm on the right track Terry. A lot of new parts to this function for me. Does this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg5r7zbs/1/) help? I'll make sure to include more code in the original question in future.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you're looking for:

```js
function zoomIn(el)
{
  // Current zoom level as a number
  const zLevel = +(el.style.zoom);
  // If current zoom level is equal or grater than 8 then set it to 8
  // otherwise double it
  el.style.zoom = (zLevel >= 8) ? 8 : (zLevel * 2);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Checkout that link to know more about the "? (ternary)" operator.

And you can use it like so:

```html
<!-- inline -->
<button id="zoomIn" onclick="zoomIn(this)">Zoom In</button>
```

Or

```js
// Zoomable element
const zoomable = document.getElementById('mainVP');
// Zoom button: this can be the zoomable element itself or any other element
document.getElementById('zoomIn').onclick = e => {
  zoomIn(zoomable);
};
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the above Nasa. Where do the second two pieces of code go? They don't look like they go inline in the element tags to me? I also have no idea whats going on here:
`   const zLevel = +(el.style.zoom);
    el.style.zoom = (zLevel >= 8) ? 8 : (zLevel * 2); `
This looks circular to me.
If anyone fancies walking me through the whole thing I think I'll learn a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, particularly Nasa. Nasa's answer appears to be far more concise than my eventual solution and I now know about ternary operators. But I simply don't yet know how to use the 'zoomable element' or 'zoom button' sections of the code. I will revisit this once I am a little more knowledgeable. I returned to my original technique for now and after some debugging realised that getElementById was returning 0. So I have used getComputedStyle instead:

```
  function zoomIn() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("mainVP"); 
      var zoomNow = 
          window.getComputedStyle( 
              elem, null).getPropertyValue("zoom");
    if (zoomNow == 8) {
      document.getElementById('mainVP').style.zoom = 8;
    } else {
      zoomNow = zoomNow*2;
      document.getElementById('mainVP').style.zoom = zoomNow;
    }
}
```